# ExpressionEngine Rich Text - the HTML Output is coming out weird

Tags: templates, custom-fields, richtext

- In EE's Rich Text editor, I typed in the following content.
- I did not do any fancy markup or formatting.
- All I did was set each heading to an H4, and typed paragraphs normally.
- I did not touch the code or alter any markup.

This is how EE is outputting my (fairly normal) text in my template:

```
    <h4>The Project</h4>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <div>
            <p>An iconic Lorem Ipsum led shopping centre at Location X. The 65,000 square&nbsp;foot multi-use facility includes a Lorem&nbsp;Ipsum Store built upon stilts to house&nbsp;customer parking underneath, together&nbsp;with 28 retail units, a food court, a&nbsp;petrol filling station and 18,000 square feet of office space.</p>
            <div>
                <p></p>
                <div>
                    <p></p>
                    <div>
                        <p>The focus of the design was to make a bold architectural statement and&nbsp;included an ambitious six-storey high,&nbsp;frameless, glass frontage with an&nbsp;unusual curved roof.&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h4>The Challenge</h4>
            <div>
                <p></p>
                <div>
                    <p></p>
                    <div>
                        <p>Creating an innovative glass structure,&nbsp;24 metres high with a 10 degree angled lean. Nothing quite like this had ever been attempted in Europe before.&nbsp;It was a first and whilst Company Name had to ensure they were highly attentive to the practical safety aspects of&nbsp;achieving the construction, they also&nbsp;had to think about the clients aesthetic&nbsp;objectives to creating a striking piece&nbsp;of architecture that would draw in&nbsp;shoppers.&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am confused why so many blank `<p>` tags are output, and why each subsequent paragraph is nested further and further into a series of nested `<div>`s. Is this normal behaviour for EE? It breaks my styling slightly, as `<div>` have small margins on them. If I were to code this manually, I would put something like `<h4>The Project</h4> <p>The text[...]</p>` - without wrapping the `<p>` in a `<div>`.

Is there anything I can do about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst this does not solve the issue that you are having with the WYSIWYG editor that is provided with ExpressionEngine, you can upgrade to a different WYSIWYG add-on like [Editor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/editor) or [Wygwam](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam).

Both of these are robust though I prefer Editor because it also adds WYSIWYG to the category description field. Though to be honest these are both fantastic add-ons.

Comment: Thank you - I am now using Editor, which seems to understand the markup perfectly!